# How Can I add XML declaration?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, declaration

I Have this Xml output from URL [XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phEiz.jpg)
using HTTP GET method

How Can I add this XML declaration?

> ?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

This is ServiceContract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
          [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
          ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
          //BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
          UriTemplate = "{id}")]

    XElement GetRecipesByID(string id);
```

This is implementation,
I convert DataTable To Xml and get from URL

```
public XElement GetRecipesByID(string id)
    {
        StringWriter str = new StringWriter();
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.Tables.Add(Table);
        XmlTextWriter xtext = new XmlTextWriter(str);
        xtext.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        xtext.WriteStartDocument();
            xtext.WriteStartElement("rss");
            xtext.WriteAttributeString("version", "2.0");
            xtext.WriteStartElement("channel");
            xtext.WriteElementString("title", "GetCard");
            xtext.WriteElementString("link", "10.0.0.253");
            xtext.WriteElementString("lastBuildDate", " ");
            xtext.WriteElementString("generator", "Alikas Feed");
            xtext.WriteElementString("error", error);
            xtext.WriteElementString("cardid", "RX0016502");
            xtext.WriteElementString("name", " ");
            xtext.WriteElementString("passport_id", "60001082881");
            xtext.WriteElementString("tel", " ");
            xtext.WriteEndElement();
            xtext.WriteEndDocument();

            result = str.ToString();

        xtext.Close();

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Save(str);


        return XElement.Parse(result);

    }
```

When I save this xml in file there is xml declaration but when I try to get this xml from URL xml declaration doesn't show. 
I need to show this declaration from URL.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`WriteStartDocument` should already be adding the XML declaration. It uses the `Encoding` specified by your `TextWriter`.

You're using a `StringWriter` which will always report UTF-16 as .NET Strings are in UTF-16. To get ISO-8859-1, you'll need to construct a `StreamWriter` or some other `TextWriter` with an explicit encoding.

Have you considered creating an `XDocument` directly? No need to use `XmlWriter` in that case.

Comment: Yes, I tried with XDocument but same result. 
when I write this xml in file I have XML declaration  but in Chrome doesn't show.

Comment: If it's in the file it's in the file, so sounds like it's not a code issue. Chrome just isn't showing it.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me

```
XDocument xel = XDocument.Parse(  "<root><el>123</el></root>" );
xel.Declaration = new XDeclaration( "1.0","UTF-8","true" );
xel.Save( @"c:\temp.xml" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            string header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?><rss version=\"2.0\"/>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(header);

            XElement rss = doc.Root;

            Boolean error = false;
            rss.Add(new XElement("channel", new object[] {
                new XElement("title", "GetCard"),
                new XElement("link", "10.0.0.253"),
                new XElement("lastBuildDate", " "),
                new XElement("generator", "Alikas Feed"),
                new XElement("error", error),
                new XElement("cardid", "RX0016502"),
                new XElement("name"),
                new XElement("passport_id", "60001082881"),
                new XElement("tel")
            }));

            doc.Save(@"c:\temp\test.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an special method for this:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "ISO-8859-1", null);
xmlDoc.Save(str);
```

Note from the msdn on encoding parameter: This is the encoding that is used when you save the XmlDocument to a file or a stream; therefore, it must be set to a string supported by the Encoding class, otherwise Save fails.